# How to import module from npmjs as Typescript not Javascript instead of using require [Ionic]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

As I mention, I want to import a module but I don't understand the document.
I'm using Ionic for develop an app.
I install the module :

> npm install wordnet

Instead of using ..

```
var wordnet = require('wordnet');

wordnet.lookup('define', function(err, definitions) {

  definitions.forEach(function(definition) {
    console.log('  words: %s', words.trim());
    console.log('  %s', definition.glossary);
  });
});
```

How to use the module in the Typescript file for using it function.. as

```
import { wordnet } from 'wordnet'
```

Do I need to import module in app.module.ts or in the page page.module.ts or something...?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup.  If you're using AngularCLI, then it should find the TypeScript / JavaScript code automagically.  Check your node-modules directory to make sure the code is there.  If not add the `--save-dev` flag when you install:

```
npm install --save-dev wordnet
```

IF this library relies on binary assets or CSS files, then you may have to edit the angular-cli.json file to tell it where to find image or CSS files.  Here is a snippet from the AngularCLI conversion I did in my [Learn With](https://www.learn-with.com) books that shows how I set up assets and CSS.

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "assets": [
        "img",
        {
          "glob": "**/*",
          "input": "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/fonts",
          "output": "./fonts"
        }
      ],
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css",
        "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css"
      ],
    }
  ],
```

If you're using SystemJS to load modules then you'll have to set up wordnet in your SystemJS config.  Generally something like this:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        map: {
            'wordnet': 'path/to/wordnet/code'
        },
    });
})(this);
```